# In C# MVC why is throwing an exception when Razor model from ViewModel

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .post

I am using MVC with C#,

Here is my ViewModel class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{        
    public MySqlConnectionStringBuilder Con { get; set; }// Without this property everything is working fine.
    public string PrName { get; set; }
    public string Aky { get; set; }
    public string Sky { get; set; }
}
```

My Razor View:

```
@model MySQLDB
<form class="form-horizontal myform" action="/MyAction">
@Html.TextBoxFor(mode => Model.PrName, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Name your backup" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Con.Server, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Enter host address" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Aky, new { @Value = "ALOJUS", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Sky, new { @Value = "IJSHS9KSDFES", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
<button type="submit" name="ActionName" value="Connect" class="btn btn-default btn-connect">Connect &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

My Ajax Post:

```
$('.myform').on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();            
        $.post('/MyAction', $(this).serializeArray(), function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        });
    });
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel())
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> MyAction(MyViewModel model)
    {
        var taskResult = await Task.Run(() => {
            //do something
            return Json(new {message="success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        });
        return taskResult;
    }
```

But, getting error like `Object reference not set to instance of an object`. Even it doesn't go into my Controller breakpoint.

[image]

Answers at [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) are not fully address my question, because in my scenario there are no empty or null values from the posted form, if i remove the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` property then everything is working fine. object deserialization is not working when i use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` property in my viewmodel class. Here `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` is class defined in the meta DLL
 `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Comment: What line of code is throwing the exception (debug your code)

Comment: Where are you instantiating `MyViewModel.Con`? I don't see a `new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()` anywhere.

Comment: A MySqlConnectionStringBuilder should not be part of a ViewModel.

Comment: And as a side note, do never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of the property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke even breakpoint is not hitting in my controller. I get this error message from my browser development tool (Network) window.

Comment: Put break points in your GET method and in the view and step through it

Comment: @StephenMuecke it seems form serialized correctly. getting that error at line `$.post('/MyAction')`

Comment: @CompuChip i tried `var model = new MySQLDB();
            model.Con = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            return View(model);` but the issue not resolved.

Comment: Probably not related but you should use `$(this).serialize()` (not `serializeArray()`). You have not shown all the code in your post method,  so we cannot guess what is causing the exception.

Comment: @bommelding i need to use entities of class `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`in my razor mode, So i created another class (viewmodel) by including `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` and other entities as well. Pleas let me know if you have another approach?

Comment: @StephenMuecke tried `$(this).serialize()` instead `$(this).serializeArray()` but nothing difference

Comment: I did say it was probably not related :) You still have not shown us the code that cause that exception

Comment: Is something wrong with your layout.cshtml ?

Comment: @UtkarshBais nothing wrong with my layout.cshtml.

Comment: Try initialising the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder in your controller's constructor, and use it from there on